# how to load .class file in java application

Tags: java

I have a .class file as(JJJ.class) at location C:\Users\user\Desktop\jk ...
i want to load dynamically this .class file in java application.here i want to load .class file dynamically in the project

```
package com.load.data;
public class JJJ {

public static void main(String[] args)throws ClassNotFoundException,MalformedURLException
        {   

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\jk");



        URL url = file.toURL();         
        URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);       
        Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.load.data.JJJ");



        }


    }
```

Comment: What is you problem then? Be more specific.

Comment: file.toURL(); is deprecated method

Comment: are you getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: i want to load .class file dynamically and get results...

Answer (score 2):

The package structure must be reflected in the directory structure. If the class loader loads from `C:\Users\user\\Desktop\jk` the class must actually be stored here:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\jk\com\load\data\JJJ.class
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use your JJJ class as the class loader and check that the class you try to load is in the classpath.

```
public class JJJ {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    ClassLoader classLoader = JJJ.class.getClassLoader();

    try {
      Class aClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.load.data.JJJ");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: .class file contains a "helloworld"..but while running am not able to get results

Comment: If you use the code bellow and it does not work, first check that the class you try to load is in the classpath and then check if the class is at the right place (eg: your class com.load.data.JJJ should be in /com/load/data/JJJ.class)